# Из компьютера в андроид

Tags: python, android, pyqt5

написал простенькую программу на python'е (PyQt5, все дела...) и вот теперь имею желание вывести её на андроид. Подскажите пожалуйста, куда мне теперь идти и что смотреть/читать?

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/737257

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью инструмента [pyqtdeploy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyqtdeploy) вы можете развернуть приложение Pyqt5 для:

- Windows
- GNU/Linux
- Mac OS X
- Android
- iOS

[здесь](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/pyqtdeploy/) можете посмотреть документацию pyqtdeploy . Это инструмент gui, который упаковывает ваше приложение Pyqt5 и компилирует его для целевой платформы.

[image]

Это позволяет выбрать различные модули, чтобы включить в компиляцию:

[image]

в командной строке Вы можете использовать команду `pyqtdeploy-build`:

```
pyqtdeploy-build pyqt-demo.pdy
```